# ACRA always disabled?

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, crash-reports, acra

Here is the code I use to have ACRA but its not working,. in the LogCat I keep getting "ACRA is disabled":

Checkbox xml:

```
 <CheckBoxPreference android:key="acra.enable"
    android:title="@string/pref_disable_acra"
    android:summaryOn="@string/pref_acra_enabled"
    android:summaryOff="@string/pref_acra_disabled"
    android:defaultValue="true"/>
```

Preference class:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);

     }
}
```

Here is a picture while enabling/disabling the checkbox:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check You have added your Application in Manifest.xml file...

Only if you add it, it will be enabled....

Shanmugam